# Passing modal form data to another component not working in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-components

I have a modal (popup) and there is a form in that. When user fills that form and hit the *Add* button, I want to pass that form values to the component where is it showing.(result)

I tried it as below but it **doesn't executing** the **this.modalRef.content.onClose.subscribe** method.
Can someone point out the issue here?

**myComponent.ts**

```
modalRef?: BsModalRef | null;
constructor(private modalService: BsModalService) { }

addItem(): void{
      const initialState = {
            backdrop: true,
            ignoreBackdropClick: true,
            class: 'modal-xl',
          };

          this.modalRef = this.modalService.show(ItemProfileComponent, { ...initialState, backdrop: true, ignoreBackdropClick: true, class: 'modal-lg', });
          this.modalRef.content.onClose.subscribe((result: any) => {
            console.log(result); 
            if (result) {
              this.itemtList.push(result);
              this.itemAdd.emit(this.itemtList);
            }
          });

  }
```

**ItemProfileComponent.ts** (Modal Component)

```
public onClose: Subject<any> | undefined;
constructor(private bsModalRef: BsModalRef) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.onClose = new Subject();
  }
     close(): void {
      this.bsModalRef?.hide();
    }
```

**ItemProfileComponent.html**

```
<div class="modal-header">
    <h4 class="modal-title pull-left fw-bold" id="my-modal-title">Add New<span *ngIf="isItem"> Item</span></h4>
    <button role="button" class="btn-close close pull-right" aria-label="Close" (click)="close()">
        <span aria-hidden="true" class="visually-hidden">&times;</span>
    </button>
</div>
    
    <div class="p-2">
        <div class=" p-2">
     <!--Form-->
        <div *ngIf="!isCompany">
            <app-contact-profile [isContactHeader] = "false" [contactData] = "agentContactList" (saveContact) = "addAgentContact($event)"></app-contact-profile>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It's always be a good idea to share working sandbox link so other can understand it fully and give you appropriate solution with assuming anything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to call `next()`, pass your form data as a parameter. You should also call `complete()` to unsubscribe all subscriptions.

```js
close(): void {
   this.onClose.next(formData);
   this.onClose.complete();
   this.bsModalRef?.hide();
}
```

That's assuming you want to send the data on *every* close, you may want a separate function for when the user just wants to cancel. ie. a `submit()` and a `close()`.